# Synchronization as an alternative to a volatile declaration

Tags: java, volatile

In this tutorial ([link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/)) on Java's volatile declaration it is said that the volatile declaration can be an alternative to synchronization.

The author's example of a use of the volatile declaration:

```
volatile boolean shutdownRequested;

...

public void shutdown() { shutdownRequested = true; }

public void doWork() { 
    while (!shutdownRequested) { 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

My naive implementation of synchronization would be:

```
volatile boolean shutdownRequested;

...

synchronized public void shutdown() { shutdownRequested = true; }

synchronized public void doWork() { 
    while (!shutdownRequested) { 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

It seems that if thread A invokes `shutdown` while thread B has already invoked and is running `doWork` it would seem that thread B will continually lock execution, because it is a loop. This seems to give no opportunity for thread A to access the boolean. What did the author have in mind as the synchronized alternative to a volatile declaration?

Comment: The article begins by saying that `volatile` is not, in general, a substitute for proper formal locking.

Comment: Yes but this question is about how locking is an alternative to use of a volatile declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `// do stuff` part would be outside the synchronized block. For example, instead of `doWork` being synchronized and having `while (!shutdownRequested)`, you might have `while (!getShutDown())` where `getShutDown` is the synchronized method that returns `shutdownRequested`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way it could work:

```
public void doWork() { 
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (shutdownRequested) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // do stuff
    }
}
```